# Use environment variable with oc patch

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, buildconfig

I am currently trying to modify my image:tag in my build config from shell command using oc patch.
My command is as such :

```
oc patch bc/my-bc-name --patch '{"spec":{"strategy":{"sourceStrategy":{"from":{"name": "image:tag" }}}}}'
```

what i want to do :

```
oc patch bc/my-bc-name --patch '{"spec":{"strategy":{"sourceStrategy":{"from":{"name": $myImage }}}}}'
```

such that the image name is specify as an environnement variable.
Unfortunately, i got :
Error from server (BadRequest): invalid character '$' looking for beginning of value

using simple/double quote nor ${myImage} does not seems to work as well.

any workaround to bypass this is more than welcomed :)

Kind regards

Answer (score 5):

Surround your environment variable with single quotes as shown below. This will allow the shell to replace/expand it with its value.

```
oc patch bc/my-bc-name --patch '{"spec":{"strategy":{"sourceStrategy":{"from":{"name": "'$myImage'"}}}}}'
```

Comment: Jason, please pick an answer and close the question. Thanks